# is there a way to print not bool in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

```
`a=780
 b=90
 if (a>b):
  print(a>b)`
```

1. I do not want to print boolean
2. I just want to print (a) and print(>) and print(b)

`***  Thanks for your help

Comment: `print(f"{a}>{b}")`

Comment: `print(a, ">", b)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `print(a,' > ',b)`. Please take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_concatenation.asp.